# How to use value in dictionary to find another value in the same dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a program for a molar mass calculator. It takes the atoms and splits them up by symbol. I have a json file with the elements that includes information such as symbol and molar mass. How can I use the symbol to find the molar mass of the same element? It's in the form of a dictionary using python. In other words one value in the dictionary is the symbol, while another is the molar mass. I'd like to use the value of the symbol key to find the molar mass value.

Comment: Please provide your code, along with error and your expected result

See [How do I ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.

Comment: It seems that you need to work through a tutorial on using dictionaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could just use the [`molmass`](https://pypi.org/project/molmass/) library instead

though there's barely any documentation it's still super cool :^)

```
from molmass import Formula

print(Formula("H2O").mass)
```

output:

```
18.015287
```

and just in case you're going to make a moles calculator...

```
def getMoles(f, g):
    #given f (molecular formula in correct form) and g (grams)
    return g/Formula(f).mass
```

Comment: TIL there is a `molmass` library. Indeed there is a python library for everything...

Comment: thats the beauty of the language :)

Answer (score 0):

On your first pass through the data, convert the json file into key, value pairs such that key = symbol, value = molar mass. Once this is a dictionary, you may simply call `obj["Fe"]` to get the molar mass for Iron.

Answer (score 0):

I use the molmass module:

```
import molmass

Themolarmass = molarmass.Formula("FORMULA").mass
```